# What movie is the crew of Discovery implied to be watching at the end of Somewhere to Belong?

Tags: story-identification, movie, star-trek-discovery, reference

A recent *Star Trek: Discovery* novel, *[Somewhere to Belong](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/60701358-somewhere-to-belong?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=qimqUN7ptO&rank=4)* by Dayton Ward, has this passage towards the end:

> ...I now know that years before humanity made first contact with a nonterrestrial species, your entertainment featured numerous stories of such encounters. These dramatizations ran the gamut from peaceful interactions to full-scale invasions by aliens bent on conquest. However, there was one interesting film about a rather large group of extraterrestrials who crash on Earth and are left with no choice but to integrate into human society. Zora tells me the story of how these new arrivals face all manner of challenges before they come to accept their circumstances and turn to building a new life is really quite inspiring.

What movie could Ward be talking about here? The closest I can recall is *[District 9](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1136608/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*, but that only fits about half the premise.

Comment: I'm voting for "Coneheads."

Answer (score 5):

"[Alien Nation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Nation_(film))" perhaps?

As the summary below suggests, it does fit the bill of having a large group of extraterrestrials assimilating into human society

> In 1988, a spaceship bearing **300,000** enslaved aliens known as
> "Newcomers" lands in the Mojave Desert. By 1991, they have settled in
> Los Angeles and some of them have joined Los Angeles Police
> Department. Detective Matthew Sykes' partner is killed in a shootout
> while trying to stop a Newcomer robbery ending in the store owner's
> murder. Sykes' superior, Captain Warner, informs his squad that they
> will work with the newly promoted Newcomer detective Sam Francisco.

Comment: I'm thinking of "The People", that TV movie starring Captain Kirk that was based on the Zenna Henderson stories